# Cakephp 4 - How to merge assoaciate tables?

Tags: php, cakephp

Is it possible to combine assoaciate table as Union? To display it all together with conditions

```php
$this->paginate = [
  'contain' => ['Users', 'Posts', 'Comment', 'likes'],
];
$tweets = $this->paginate($this->lists);
```

Something like in query builder so I can also add condition for posts and comments

```php
$table1 = $this->tableName
  ->find()
  ->join()
  ->where()

$table2 = $this->tableName
  ->find()
  ->join()
  ->where()

$Union->Union($table1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following would do using [unions](https://book.cakephp.org/3/fr/orm/query-builder.html#unions)

```
$table1 = $this->tableName
  ->find()
  ->join()
  ->where()

$table2 = $this->tableName
  ->find()
  ->join()
  ->where()

$table2->union($table1);
```